What does "cause for reflection" mean?
In a duel, the cheerful singing cowboy Buster Scruggs
tries to shoot Curly Joe's brother by using a mirror's
reflection:

Buster Scruggs: His heart would be on the left,
but in the mirror it'd be on the right. Of course,
we is both facing the same way and the gun is
upside down, so...Yeah, best not to play it too fancy.

Buster Scruggs shoots Curly Joe's brother perfectly:

Buster Scruggs: Cause for reflection.

What does "cause for reflection" mean?

Please edit your answer and include the name of the movie by the Cohen bros.

A cause for reflection is
something you should give more thought to.
Ludwig says causes for reflection 'can be used when discussing topics or events that prompt deep thinking or consideration'.
Ludwig
A cause is a reason, or topic in this case.
Here the topic involves the physics of mirror reflection and how the aiming should be done with a gun pointing upside-down.
Hence reflection takes two roles.  It is the thought to give
or a discussion to make
about a cause, and the topic itself: mirror reflection.

It's a pun on the usual meaning of the phrase.
